# Rake db:migrate - how do I know if there is an unrun migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am working on an existing rails application, making changes and updating it.

How do I check if there are unrun rake db:migrate in it? Is there a direct command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running this:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Would give you this:

```
   up     20130415141113  Rename coupon to discount coupon
   up     20130416144722  Create ratings
  down    20130419102623  Add published to product
  down    20130419124429  Add attachment photo to users
```

Anything that is 'down' has NOT been migrated.

Answer (score 1):

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Will give you that information